# How to Find the dev path in which usb device is connected?

Tags: linux, usb, lsusb

I have connected two data cards in my server. One is connected in port `dev/ttyUSB2`. I want to find the other's port.

There are four ports

1. `ttyUSB0`,
2. `ttyUSB1`,
3. `ttyUSB2`,
4. `ttyUSB3`.

I already tried `lsusb -vv` and found out this:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 19d2:2003
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look it up in `dmesg` logs

```
dmesg|less
```